# How To Display GlSurfaceView in Phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, video, glsurfaceview

I have requirement in my Project. My project is Video conference call using third party library. I am doing this project in Native android and phonegap. In Native android, After succefully connect video conference call , The thrird party library gives a custom view which extends GLSurfaceView (For rendering Video). I added custom view as child of Relative layout in my Screen. So, it works well in  Native android application. But ,I have a problem in Phonegap. After succefully connect Video conference call how to send or disply GlSurfaceView in phonegap. Could please anybody give a suggestion to my problem. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put GlSurfaceView into CordovaWebView, but you can place in next/top of to each other.

Create Relative view and put both of them into it.

Comment: is there any other solution to my problem.